# Cannot import environment variable in ts-Jest with react-native-dotenv

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, ts-jest

I am trying to set up `ts-jest` with my expo project. The project currently is using `react-native-dotenv` for environment variable management. I have followed the documentaion from [`react-native-dotnet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) to create a `env.d.ts`.

In my code, i have been using `import {API} from '@env';` to import the env vironment. But every time when I run the test, it always raise `Cannot find module '@env' from 'xx.test.tsx'`

How can I use the environment variable in `ts-jest`

Here is all my setup:

```js
//jest.config.ts
import type {JestConfigWithTsJest} from 'ts-jest';
import { defaults as tsjPreset } from 'ts-jest/presets'

const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  setupFiles: ['./jest_setup/asyncStorage.ts'],
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json'
      },
    ],
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/__test__/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)',
  ],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    '!**/coverage/**',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/babel.config.js',
    '!**/jest.setup.js',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'ts',
    'tsx',
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|@react-navigation/native-stack|@firebase|firebase/.*|@react-native|react-native)',
  ],
  coverageReporters: [
    'json-summary',
    'text',
    'lcov',
  ],
  'cacheDirectory': '.jest/cache',
};

export default config;
```

```js
// env.d.ts
declare module '@env' {
    export const API: string;
};
```

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [['babel-preset-expo']],
    plugins: [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "envName": "APP_ENV",
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
      }],
      ['module-resolver', {
        "root" : ["./"],
        "alias": {
          "~": "./",
        }
      }]
    ]
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own questions. Since the project is using `babel` for the plug in to work. Therefore, by adding `babelConfig: 'your/babel/config/path'` will solve the issue.

```js
// jest.config.ts
const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
//... other stuff,

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json',
        babelConfig: 'babel.config.js'
      },
    ],
  },
//... Other stuff

}
```